# How to return GenericInternalRow from spark udf

Tags: apache-spark

I have a spark udf written in scala that takes couuple of columns and apply some logic and output InternalRow. There is spark schema of StructType also present.
But when I try to return the InternalRow from UDF there is exception

> java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Schema for type
> org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.GenericInternalRow is not supported

```
  val getData = (hash : String, type : String) => {
    val schema = hash match {
      case "people" =>
        peopleSchema
      case "empl" =>  emplSchema
    }
    getGenericInternalRow(schema)
  }

  val data = udf(getData)
```

Spark Version : 2.4.5

Comment: And InternalRow is an abstract class, why would you want to return that ???

Comment: Its GenericInternalRow. I Just used the interface of it. Even though I change the signature to return GenericInternalRow, result is same.
Edited the question.